# CSV result into multiple columns

Tags: codeigniter

My code is working fine in windows but in Linux when I export it exports all data into a single column instead of exporting into multiple columns.

Here's my code:

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$this->load->helper('download');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products");
    $csv = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query); 
    force_download('result.csv', $csv);
```

Comment: What software are you using to view the csv? When trying to open the csv in your `spreadsheet application` select `delimiter as comma`.

Comment: Its working fine in windows in ms office but when I am exporting same file using linux all data I get is in one column.

Comment: I want no matter what platform user is using csv should return data in multi columns.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the delimiter and newline options

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$this->load->helper('download');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products");
$delimiter = ";";
$newline = "\r\n";
$csv = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query,$delimiter,$newline);
force_download('result.csv', $csv);
```

Comment: I have already tried that but it didn't worked for me.Delimiter is not wokring in linux.

Comment: can you please provide me some more help.

Comment: edited, added comma as delimiter..check if it works..in both windows and linux

Comment: its downloaded well in windows?

Comment: In windows without delimiter its working perfectly fine but in linux I am facing this issue.

Comment: have you used semi-colon as delimiter?

Comment: It also not returning what I am expecting to get returned.

Comment: are the columns merged in one columns separated by comma in linux?

Comment: ok, if you use comma as delimiter then you get separated by comma but merged in one column?